# Removing outliers from LiDAR point cloud using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, lidar, filter, spatial-outliers

I have a city-wide LiDAR (LAS format) dataset that I'd like to clear of outlier points to process in ArcMap 10.7. I've identified the points using the Locate Outliers tool.

How do I use the resulting point feature class to rid the point cloud of those points?

I understand it's possible with LasTools in ArcGIS Pro, but I do not have access to it.

Comment: @Kadir Şahbaz Please try not to edit closed questions until after the OP starts to make mods, otherwise you kick off a round of reopen voting without sufficient edits.

Comment: @Vince My mistake. I haven't realized that so far. Thanks.

Comment: @Vince What if a closed question needs edits? Shouldn't we edit?

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz I was not aware of that for quite a while and learned of it through https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4658/115

Answer (score 1):

It's not ArcMap, but it is straightforward to identify noise (classification == 7) and remove it in a `pdal translate` operation:

```
pdal translate input.las output.las lof range --filters.range.limits="Classification![7:7]"
```

PDAL can be installed into your ArcMap Conda environment by using the [Conda Forge](https://conda-forge.org/) channel. See more about installing PDAL in from Conda [here](https://pdal.io/download.html#conda).

Comment: Thanks! That's an interesting approach- however I ended up implementing the lasheight tool from LAStools in ArcMap using the Iterate Files tool in ModelBuilder.